# LSTM using generator function

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create a model that has an LSTM layer of 100 units with input dimensions (16,48,12) (16 is the batch size as it takes input through a generator function). The generator function produces an expected output of (16, 1, 2) (16 is the batch size) and I want to use as output a dense layer with a softmax activation fucntion. What would be the best way to do that? I am fairly new to keras and I can't quiet get the grasp of using generator functions...

Comment: Can you provide some code to indicate what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, it is recommended to use the PReLU activation function before the fully connected dense layer.
For example：
`model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(train_X.shape[1],train_X.shape[2])))`
`model.add(BatchNormalization())`
`model.add(Dropout(.2))`
`model.add(Dense(64))`
`model.add(PReLU())`

Comment: Can you provide a reference on where it is recommended to use PReLU? That would depend on the task and data which is not present in the question description.